# $y''=2\arctan(y)+\frac{3}{2}y'-\frac{1}{2}\pi$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

As part of a more difficult question, I need to solve this IVP:

$y''=2\arctan(y)+\frac{3}{2}y'-\frac{1}{2}\pi$

Where $y(0) = 1, y'(0) = 0$

I don't know how to solve this problem, I resorted to guessing and trial and error but not a clue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The IVP  has  a unique solution and the constant function $1$ is  a solution. .......

Comment: Did you just guess that or is there a method to solving these?

Comment: @fred What theorem on NON-linear ODE's guarantees that the IVP has a unique solution.

Comment: Picard-Lindelöf

Comment: Fred the PL theorem applies to first order ODEs.  This is a second order ODE.

Comment: Write this second order ODE as a first order system. ......

Answer (score 4):

Let us assume that the class of functions in which we look for a soution is that of analytic functions in the vicinity of $x=0$. This assumption of analyticity is normally tacitly made in ODE problems.

Then consider the expansion of $y(x)$ in powers of $x$ about $x=0$.

From the initial conditions we have

$$y(0) = 1, y'(0) = 0$$

Now from the ODE

$$y''(x) = 2 \text{arctan}(y(x)) +\frac{3}{2} y'(x) - \frac{\pi}{2}\tag{1}$$

we have at $x=0$

$$y''(0) = 2 \text{arctan}(y(0)) - \frac{\pi}{2} = \frac{\pi}{2} - \frac{\pi}{2} = 0$$

The third derivative is obtained by differentiating the ODE and is given by

$$y'''(x) = \frac{3 y''(x)}{2}+\frac{2 y'(x)}{y(x)^2+1}$$

and this vanishes at $x=0$ as well.

This can be extended to all higher derivatives which all vanish (the proof is not difficult).

Hence the solution is $y(x) = 1$, as given previously by Fred.

**Observation**

The solution with the specific initial condition is very Special in that it is constant. Any other Initial condition gives rise to growing or oscillating solutions.

Consider the situation at large values of $y(x)$:

For $|y(x)| >> 1$ we have  $\text{arctan}(y(x)) \to \frac{\pi}{2}$ and the ODE simplifies approximateley to

$$y''(x) = \frac{3}{2} y(x)' + \frac{\pi}{2}\tag{2}$$

and the general solution is

$$y(x) = - x\frac{\pi}{3} + a \frac{2}{3} e^{x^{\frac{3}{2}}} + b\tag{3}$$

Where $a$ and $b$ are two constants.

Notice that for $x\gt 0$ the solution diverges over exponentially.

For negative $x$ we let $-x \to z>0$ and since $y''(z) = y''(x)$ and $y'(z) = - y'(x)$ (2) transforms to

$$y''(z) = -\frac{3}{2} y(z)' + \frac{\pi}{2}\tag{2a}$$

and the solution becomes

$$y(z) = z\frac{\pi}{3} + a \frac{2}{3} e^{-z^{\frac{3}{2}}} + b\tag{3a}$$

Comment: I'm pretty sure you meant $2arctan(1)$

Comment: @ Ryan Greyling You are completely right. $2 arctan(y(0)) = 2 arctan(1)$. Thank you for pointing this error out. Thanks also to the corrector.

Comment: The vanishing of all derivatives at $0$ does not imply that the function is $0$.  For example, the function $f$ with $f(x)=e^{-1/x^2}$ for $x\ne0$ and $f(0)=0$ is such that $f^{(n)}(0)=0$ for all $n$.

Comment: @ Mark Viola You are right, and your appropriate example here would be $f(x) = 1 + e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}}$. But I tacitly assumed the solution to be analytic at $x=0$ so that your example is ruled out.

Comment: Perhaps you could make your assumption explicit for future readers.

Comment: I have made the assumptions explicit. But, honestly, did you see such an assumptions in ODE problems? Another approach would be utilizing the uniqueness theorem of ODEs. Once we have found a solution which fufills the ODE and the initial conditions this is the only solution.